# IIS stop site show maintenance page html

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, server

When Site stop on IIS. I need to display some maintenance page

i have tried using "error-page" on IIS but its not working for me

```
<httpErrors>
        <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/maintenance.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

i added this in my web.config still it is not working

Do you have any idea !

Comment: please visit this URL "http://test.brnd.com/" i got "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found." error

Comment: iiscan not handle error while closed. Something might be considered at the loadbalancer level

Comment: then how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

It's obviously that if you stop your web server nothing will show. Because web server doesn't work and wouldn't serve any content. In your case custom HTML Page.I think that for your purpose you could use approach which call [reverse proxy.](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/)

[image]
1)At first, you should set up Nginx or another web server in front of your IIS  as reverse proxy.

2)Then configure Nginx timeout settings.You can configure how long your reverse proxy should wait for IIS server response before return to client 504 Gateway Timeout.This settings looks like

```
proxy_connect_timeout       300;
proxy_send_timeout          300;
proxy_read_timeout          300;
send_timeout                300;
```

3)After that, you should provide your custom error page when 504 Gateway Timeout has occurred.For this in Nginx Server settings write something like that.

```
server {
        . . .

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
        location = /custom_50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }

        . . .
}
```

You can find a really details explanation each of this steps in the web.My instruction provides hight level explanation, how to solve your problem.I hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is still running, then you can put the html in the default site and this will be served when the site is down.

[image: default web site]